How to use continuous infinitive

I'd like to go there now

I'd like to be going there now


Both examples are correct and 2 is better at showing and emphasizing that the action is heppaning now. Can we do the same wih these verbs?

I love to be doing it now

I like to be doing it now

I prefer to be doing it all the time

I prefer to be doing it when she comes


What do you think about 3 and 4? When it comes to 5 "prefer" is rather used to talk about something general not specific that's why I want to justify continuous infintive there by either showing duration or that I already do something before she comes. So what are your thoughts?


I would like to be going there is not talking about "now". The speaker is expressing their desire to go to that place.



I would like to set out for that place now.

I wish I was on the way there at this moment.

and 4. seem unnatural to me - better to say something like I'm enjoying [doing it].

I'm not sure what actual verb would fit here. Perhaps When I'm at a lecture, I prefer to be taking notes all the time rather than writing them down at the end. But the continuous tense isn't obligatory in such sentences.

Whenever she visits, I like to be engaged in a certain activity at the time she arrives.



is my 6 okay too? 3 and 4 not natural but grammatical right?

Sorry - I got the numbering wrong and now the system won't let me correct it.  The last two points should refer to (5) and (6). A sentence can be 'grammatical' without necessarily meaning anything; witness the famous Colourless green ideas sleep furiously.
